# MongoDB initial sync very slow

Tags: mongodb

We're syncing a new server to our MMAPv1 replica set, and since this one uses the wiredTiger storage engine, we have to do an initial sync.

Right now the process is inserting only several thousands documents per hour. Is there a way to debug what is the bottleneck?

Both CPU and IO seem not to be a problem, this is a sample iostat:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           1.99    0.05    0.52    4.01    1.00   92.43
```

The new server is syncing from a secondary, which has similar metrics.

Answer (score 2):

We had `fastsync=true` inside the configuration file. With this setting the server only replicated new data, not existing data.